# Spark Parallelism in Standalone Mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to run spark in standalone mode in my system. The current specification of my system is 8 cores and 32 Gb memory. Base on [this article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) I calculate the spark configurations as the following:

```
spark.driver.memory 2g
spark.executor.cores 3
spark.executor.instances 2
spark.executor.memory 20g
maximizeResourceAllocation TRUE
```

I created spark context in my jupyter notebook like this and was checking the parallelism level, by this

```
sc = SparkContext()
sc.defaultParallelism
```

The default parallelism is giving me 8. My question is why it's giving me 8 even though I mentioned 2 cores? If it's not giving me the actual parallelism of my system, then how to get the actual level of parallelism?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sc.defaultParallelism
```

returns default level of parallelism defined on SparkContext.By default it is number of cores available to application.

but to know what are the setting ***pre-applied*** for  jupyter  note book, you can print

```
 sc._conf.getAll()
```

from scala `sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)`

That should have the property

> spark.default.parallelism

I think in this case its preset thats why you are getting 8 in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And it's very useful. Yes I could print all my conf. And in the print, I was getting the same config as I mentioned in the config.default file. But my question was if I'm mentioning my executors to be 2 and cores 3, then still why it's showing default 8? Should it not be default 3? Or is there some difference between executor core and default core for parallelism? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. by default it is number of cores available to application. that's 3. but in your case `spark.default.parallelism` was set to  8 as default thats why you are getting 8. may be jupyter start of the session it was set

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I already upvoted it. Will accept it as answer as well  :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my mac has 1 CPU and only 4 cores but when I would do

```
sc.defaultParallelism
```

I always got 8.

So I kept wondering why that was and finally figured out it was hyper threading enabaled on the cpu that gives you 8 logical cpu's on the mac

```
$ sysctl hw.physicalcpu hw.logicalcpu
hw.physicalcpu: 4
hw.logicalcpu: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, if someone faces the same needs in **cluster execution** with pyspark (version > 2.3.X), I had to recover the variable as below: 
`spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` and then I used python to get only the value of the spark.default.parallelism key.
Just in case!
Thanks!